# Gothenburg Airport Transfer

Tags: airport-transfer, got, gothenburg

What are the transfer options for Gothenburg Airport?

The last time I took the airport coaches but they're pretty expensive. GOT is very close to the city center, shouldn't public busses or taxi be an option?